# Computer wont finish booting after I install a third graphics card

Tags: linux, boot, graphics-card, xubuntu

I'm running xubuntu on [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007QWIA52) motherboard and three [sapphire 7950](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0098HW1HG) graphics cards. The computer boots and works fine when I have just two of them installed, but when I attach the third the computer stops booting in the middle of the Xubuntu loading screen.

I don't think that this is being caused by lack of power because I'm using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007W5TV6K) 1600 Watt power supply and I'm able to navigate around the bios page just fine.

What could be causing this? Any suggestions on how to fix?

---

This is what I found when I go into advanced mode and look at the `boot.log`

[image]

and it keeps on giving me the message

```
udevd[340]: timeout: killing /sbin/modprobe -vb pci:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [350]
```

---

When I do as khajvah suggests and enter advanced mode and then as root run `sudo startx` I get

```
Fatal server error:
could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX1-lock
```

and

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth:  error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

here is the whole message

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that board supports three-way crossfire? Very few motherboards do. Additionally, what else are you running to need 1600W of power? If you can get past the BIOS, power is likely *not* the issue, as the system is stress-tested to some degree at that point. However, if it's not a certified PSU, you could run into issues.

Comment: If it was power related, the computer wouldn't pass the POST. Maybe it's a specific problem with xubuntu and multiple graphics support.

Comment: @LyleBrown the board has 6 ports for graphics cards and I know of [others](http://www.coinminingrigs.com/how-to-build-a-6-gpu-mining-rig/) using it for this purpose. The power supply is only being used to power the three graphics cards, the hard drive and the mother board.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard The only reason I'm curious of the PSU brand is because 1600W isn't very common, and cheap PSUs of that wattage can cause issues AFTER a POST. Unfortunately, I know this from experience.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B007W5TV6K/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) is the PSU I'm using, and I think it's a fairly good one.

Comment: @Loourr Can you boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)? If you can, boot into root shell and watch kernel logs.

Comment: Your power supply is a generic power supply it might be fine but it's certainly not a mainstream brand

Comment: @khajvah I added a picture of the boot.log from recovery mode

Comment: @Loourr Try to `startx`, while logged in. It should start the xfce. I don't think it is possible to tell anything from the error, because it just says that it failed to `modprobe` a device. If it fails to start the x, you will see some messages and if you system doesn't reboot you can [change to another tty](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1757976) and watch xorg logs

Comment: @khajvah I updated what happens when I try startx

Comment: @Loourr I strongly suggest you to post this question in [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/). If this is OS related, those guys will for sure help you. I really think this is OS, more specifically xorg related.